# How do you set HTTP header value for an Ext.data.Store's REST proxy in Sencha Touch 2.3?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.3

I've got this code in a button tap event:

```
var skustore = Ext.getStore('productsstore');

skustore.getProxy.setHeaders({'Session-Token': sess});
```

Prior to this I've set a value for sess.

I keep getting the error msg "Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function".

How may I achieve my objective? Variable sess is set based on the response from a server so the value cannot be hard-coded.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be just a typo, but `getProxy` is no property of the store. Use `getProxy()` instead.